# How to create multiple select Ajax base layerd in magento with color swatch

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, ajax, color-swatches, multiple-select-layered

In my site layered navigation..when i click on nay one then its ..remove rest selectors...I want to create a multiple select ajax based layered extension.....for this which files i have to be rewrite....I need basic Idea like which file i chose for that...I know extension development....Only i want to know...the which file is responsible for this.....
By which block and models we can rewrite for this task.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to  rewrite these `blocks`

```
<catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <category_view>NAMESPACE_MODULENAME_Block_Rewrite_BLOCKNAME</category_view>
                </rewrite> 
            </catalog>  

            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer_view>NAMESPACE_MODULENAME_Block_Rewrite_BLOCKNAME</layer_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>          
            <catalogsearch>
                <rewrite>
                    <result>NAMESPACE_MODULENAME_Block_Rewrite_BLOCKNAME</result>
                </rewrite> 
            </catalogsearch>
```

Comment: should i set my design concept like css in also blocks

Comment: yes you create the style concept in block too...